# deployment error for Entilement object

Tags: apex, community, salesforcedx, ant, sfdx-plugin

I'm trying to deploy entitlement object meta data, layouts, and fields through ant tool. However, I keep getting an error:

Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )

Anybody having some idea on this, how to resolve? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error, it seems that Entitlement object is not recognized yet as a standard object.

To fix this, ensure that [Entitlement Management is enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_enabling.htm&type=5) first in the target org before deploying the object metadata components.

Comment: It is already enabled

Comment: @Ananga apart from entitlement metadata, do you have any other components in the same deployment package ?